# SSD suddenly not recognized anymore in MacBook Air

Tags: macos, boot, ssd

Last night I turned off my MacBook Air A1465 with no problems at all. No hanging application or force shutdowns, but when I woke it up today, I get prompted with a map and a question mark.

I've checked for the SSD in Disk utility with no success. It's not found there.

I've opened it up, removed and replaced the stick, no success. Any ideas – or is it as simple as a broken SSD? The computer is three months old and has been used for surfing.

Comment: 3 month of internet browsing shouldn't break an SSD drive. Has it experienced any physical shock ?

Comment: @Kwaio [Don't SSDs break, a lot, independent of use?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/05/the-hot-crazy-solid-state-drive-scale.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Mac is only three months old (thus, covered under warranty) and your SSD drive does not work, have it sent in for a replacement.

There's no harm done from your attempts to reconnect the SSD, as it's the only user-serviceable part in the MacBook Air.